# 'TemplateDoesNotExist': template loader appears to be searching non-existent routes

Tags: python, django

I'm receiving a TemplateDoesNotExist error when I click on a particular link, and I've noticed from the 'template-loader postmortem' that Django is searching incorrect and non-existent paths.

I've recently moved half of the contents of a Django app called 'reviews' into another called 'accelerators'. My templates directory for each app follows the pattern: '"app name"/templates(folder)/"app name"/html templates'.

Having moved the template into the accelerators app (and having updated my settings and urls), Django should be looking for the template via 'accelerators/templates/accelerators/accelerator_form.html', but according to the error message it's instead searching: 'accelerators/templates/reviews/accelerator_form.html'.

I suspect this has something to do with the fact that I've just moved this template, alongside a number of other files, from the reviews app, but I can't figure out why this is happening. I've included my updated urls etc. below for reference.

Base directory urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('reviews/', include('reviews.urls')),
    path('accelerators/', include('accelerators.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

accelerators/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    AcceleratorListView, 
    accelerator_detail,
    accelerator_reviews,
    AcceleratorCreateView, 
    AcceleratorUpdateView, 
    AcceleratorDeleteView,
)
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', AcceleratorListView.as_view(), name='accelerators'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.accelerator_detail, name='accelerator_detail'),
    path('new/', AcceleratorCreateView.as_view(), name='accelerator_create'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', AcceleratorUpdateView.as_view(), name='accelerator_update'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', AcceleratorDeleteView.as_view(), name='accelerator_delete'),
    path('<int:pk>/reviews/', views.accelerator_reviews, name='accelerator_reviews'),
]
```

accelerators/views.py (view that I'm trying to access)

```
class AcceleratorCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Accelerator
    fields = ['name', 'website', 'locations', 'bio', 'sector_focus', 'stage', 'deal', 'duration', 'logo']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

base.html template (relevant link)

```
<li><a class="dropdown-link" href="{% url 'accelerator_create' %}">Add Company</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because your `Accelerator` model is still coming from **review app** i.e. from `review.models`.

Django searches for template in **`templates/app_name/model_name_type.html`** if it not provided specifically.

> **2 Solutions:** Follow any of them

1. **Provide `template_name` specifically**.

```
class AcceleratorCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Accelerator
    template_name = 'accelerators/accelerator_form.html'
```

2. **Move your `Accelerator` model to `models file of accelerators` app.**

Comment: @samalty, check it and let me know if this work for you?

Comment: 'template_name' did the job. Thanks!